# PHP cURL behaviour like html form?

Tags: php, curl

Hi is there any way to use cURL like form?

For example I have url `mysite.com/curly.php` which have the cURL script that target to `mysite.com/straight.php` that will display every data that I posted from `curly.php`

Here is my code:

```
$url = "http://mysite.my/curly.php";
$curl = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "order_id=123&bill_total=1000000&merchant_id=99999&merchant_name=myname&custName=customer");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

straight.php

```
echo $_POST['order_id'];
echo $_POST['bill_total'];
echo $_POST['merchant_id'];
echo $_POST['merchant_name'];
echo $_POST['customer_name'];
```

When I use `header("Location: " . $url);` it only showed me a blank page.

EDIT:
**FOR THOSE WHO DONT UNDERSTAND WHAT I WANT. 
I NEED TO OPEN straight.php on my address bar with posted data (redirect?) know what i mean?**

Comment: Why are you using  header("Location: " . $url); ??

Comment: i want to open the straight.php with posted data

Comment: you have wrote this code "header("Location: " . $url); " in straight.php right? It will not work . Use session to store it and the print the session after cUrl execution.

Comment: downvote if you have some answer!

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use

```
header("Location: " . $url);
```

the curl is posting your parameters to the url

use

```
$mypage = curl_exec($curl);
echo $mypage ;
```

to see what happened in that url what the page returned after the post